# React Native -PreactNativeArchitectures=x86 always builds all ABIs. How to build only one?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I created a new react-native project with:

```
npx react-native init foo
```

Then In `foo/android` I ran:

```
 ./gradlew clean bundleRelease -PreactNativeArchitectures=x86
```

I would expect it to create a .aab file that only contains x86 architecture, but it seems it always has all the architecture ABIs? Looking inside the .aab file it has all the folders:

[image]

Also if I run `./gradlew clean bundleRelease`

I get the exact same size .aab file with the exact same folder structure, again with all architectures included.

Is `-PreactNativeArchitectures` bugged or am I using it wrong? How do I only create one architecture for a release bundle and how do I know it's working? Currently `-PreactNativeArchitectures` seems to be completely ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from Cortinico in Github: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34902

Turns out ABI split are not supported by .aab files. One should build .apk file instead with:

```
./gradlew clean assembleRelease -PreactNativeArchitectures=x86
```

Also need to set the following to true in `android/app/build.gradle`

```
 def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
```